# ReactJS Sort Column Table localCompare throws erorr on column associated with ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a react js Table with columns with sorting functionality. The columns with just text are working fine, but I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of undefined

I am assuming or guessing localeCompare only works with text column, it bombs on the columns with integers. correct?

My sort function is

```
SortTable(event, sortKey) {

if (!this.state.ascending) {
            this.state.application.sort((a,b) => a[sortKey].localeCompare(b[sortKey]))
            this.state.ascending = true
         
        } else {
            this.state.application.sort((a,b) => b[sortKey].localeCompare(a[sortKey]))
            this.state.ascending = false    
         
        }
}
```

My table code is the following

```
<Table striped bordered>
                                        <thead style={{'background-color': 'rgb(248,248,255)'}}>
                                            <tr>
                                <th   onClick={e=> this.sortTable(e,'myId')}>
                                                    <Button s 
                                                    <div>Phase<i className={this.state.iconName}/></div></Button></th>
</tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>

                <td style={{textAlign:'center'}}>{this.getStringBaseOnId(myId)}</td>
            
             
            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </Table>
```

The function looks like

```
getStringBaseOnId(id) {
  return 'Test'
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you have a typo in your function argument (`sortyKey`). Is that the case?

Comment: you need to check if value is null and assign blank using pipe, also your function has parameter sortyKey, but you are checking against sortKey